# AWS API gateway High Availability setup in us-east-2 and us-west-2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, api-gateway

I have followed step by step the instructions in the following documentation:

1. [Multi-region serverless app with API Gateway and Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-multi-region-serverless-application-with-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/)
2. [API Gateway HA setup in us-east-1 and us-east-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038613/aws-api-gateway-high-availability-setup-in-us-east-1-and-us-east-2)

but when I run:

```
curl -v --location --request POST 'https://mydomain.example.com/basepath/path'
```

**EDIT:**

I get the following output:

```
*   Trying 3.23.57.129:443...
* Connected to mydomain.example.com (3.23.57.129) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Jul  1 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 30 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match mydomain.example.com
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'mydomain.example.com'
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'mydomain.example.com'
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

**EDIT2:**

I've 2 records configured in my hosted zone at Route53, like both documentations suggest. These are the records according to the AWS API I've deployed in us-east-2 and us-west-2:

```
Record name: mydomain.example.com
Record Type: CNAME
Value: XXX500mdd4.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com (the domain of the api deployed over us-east-2)
Alias: No
TTL: 60 seconds
Routing policy: Failover
Health check ID: 2fcf9c25-25f0-486f-b351-c1df0562bb1d


Record name: mydomain.example.com
Record Type: CNAME
Value: sinbpssYYY.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com (the domain of the api deployed over us-west-2)
Alias: No
TTL: 60 seconds
Routing policy: Failover
Health check ID: 276e957a-77ed-4471-8a43-ee3eff00626a
```

The first record is configured as the primary, and the second one as the secondary. I've followed exactly the ideas stated at both cited documentations, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong

**EDIT3:**

For validate the generated certificate I followed the AWS documentation for DNS Validation (the same you supplied in your link). For that purpose I followed the steps in the topic "**To set up DNS validation in the console**". That is:

1. Opened the ACM console
2. Selected the certificate from the list
3. Then, in the **Domain** section, I used the **Create records in Route 53** button. I performed these steps for the certificate requested in us-east-2 and also for the one requested in us-west-2

After performing these actions for the us-east-2 region, the following record appears in the hosted Zone at Route 53:

```
Record name: _85e39035fc67b4892c097f367cab18b0.mydomain.example.com
Record Type: CNAME
Value: _8f9709078cc0246638fe9e1a2571ff17.fpktwqqglf.acm-validations.aws.
Alias: No
TTL: 300 seconds
Routing policy: Simple
```

However, when I complete the steps for the certificate requested in us-west-2, no other record appears at the hosted zone. I've the hypothesis, that since both domains (the one requested in us-east-2 and that on us-west-2) have the same name (mydomain.example.com), the other record that would supposedly be added when requesting the certificate in us-west-2 region would have the same name and that is why only one record was added to validate both certificates in us-east-2 and us-west-2 region.

**EDIT4:**

When I bought the domain, the hosted zone was automatically created too, with the followings two records:

```
Record name: example.com
Record Type: NS
Value: ns-31.awsdns-03.com, ns-1919.awsdns-47.co.uk, ns-741.awsdns-28.net, ns-1192.awsdns-21.org
Alias: No
TTL: 172800 seconds
Routing policy: Simple

Record name: example.com
Record Type: SOA
Value: ns-31.awsdns-03.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
Alias: No
TTL: 900 seconds
Routing policy: Simple
```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: The command flag `-v` provides the details to debug this problem. Those details are not included in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I've edited the question and added the output I get from executing curl. Any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and show how you configured DNS for the hostname `mydomain.example.com`.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've edited my question and added the information you suggest me. Anything, you think and should add in order to detect what produces this error please tell me, thanks!!

Comment: Next, verify the DNS validation records: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/dns-validation.html Put those records in your question.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I've edited again the question adding the information you requested. Any suggestion?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong. The only thing left is to make sure you are creating the DNS resource records at the correct (authoritative) DNS server.

Comment: how can I make sure the records area created at the correct place? how can I check that? @JohnHanley

Comment: Your domain registrar controls which DNS servers are authoritative. There are DNS testing sites such as mxtoolbox.com that can tell you what your NS (Name Servers) are. Verify that the NS records match the servers where you created the DNS records. If you create DNS records at the wrong server, they have no effect. For example, you configure a hosted zone at Route 53, but you did not update the NS records for your domain at the registrar.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've done everything at AWS Console. In fact, when I bought the domain, the hosted zone was created automatically with two records. I've edited the question and showed these two records in EDIT4, that is what you are referring at?

Comment: At this point, I have run out of options. Use an Internet tool, such as mxtoolbox.com, that can read your DNS records and verify that they report the same values that you created.

Comment: Thanks you a lot @JohnHanley, I'll do that

Comment: Hi, @JohnHanleyfinally, I read again all the documentation AWS supplied regarding this topic and I made changes in the configuration of the Route53 records, instead of defining them as CNAME I used A. Also I use alias to an API Gateway. I was able to connect to the endpoints, but the failover routine does not function. However that is another issuer I probably post in another question